# How to execute a script without password and root privileges

Tags: unix

i am trying to execute a script as a non root user.password is required here to execute the script. Am able to execute the script with password as a non root user.is there any possible way to execute the script without root privileges and also without entering the password.

Comment: That completely depends on the script. Most likely answer though: no. If it was a serious script, it wouldn't require root privileges if it didn't need them.

Answer (score 0):

If a script requires root privileges to run, there is no way to *legally* circumvent that and run the script without such privileges.